# Complexity of an algorithm with nested loops

Tags: time-complexity

How do I calculate the complexity of this Algorithm below? I would like to know how I calculate the sums that form to obtain a formula as a function of n? I know that in general this algorithm has O(n^3) complexity, but how can I do that?

```
int i,j,k,s;

for(i=0; i < N-1; i++)

    for(j=i+1; j < N; j++)

        for(k=1; k < j; k++)

        s = 1;
```

On

Comment: I would just like to know how to put together the sums to arrive at the closed formula. Obviously the algorithm is O(n^3)

Comment: As written, this program can be replaced by a single if statement. Unfortunately, your question is unclear, and it is very unlikely anyone could answer it without further details. In particular, [type here]. We will put the question on-hold for the time being, but you will still be able to edit and improve it. Once you clarify the question you can flag it to get our attention. See our [FAQ#close] for further details!